# How to stream from disk in kurento? (with node.js)

Tags: kurento

How can I stream a file from disk (with node.js)? I rummaged through all the documentation and found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
presenter[watchUserId].pipeline.create('PlayerEndpoint', {uri: 'file:///var/www/domain/public/webm2/file.webm', networkCache: 0 }, (err, playerEndpoint) => {
                    if(err){
                        console.error('error at create PlayerEndpoint');
                        presenter[watchUserId].pipeline.release();
                        callback(err);
                    }
```

as example. 
Just use PlayerEndpoint with file:/// in uri.

and then

```
playerEndpoint.connect(webRtcEndpoint, function(err){
                                    if(err){
                                        console.error('error at create connect');
                                        presenter[watchUserId].pipeline.release();
                                    }

                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                        playerEndpoint.play(function(err){
                                            console.error(err);
                                        });
                                    }, 5000);

                                });
```

connect playerEndpoint and webRtcEndpoint